# Element-wise comparison of vectors of tuples julia

Tags: vector, tuples, comparison, julia

In Julia, why is the following element-wise comparison returning a vector containing false

```
julia> [(1,)] .== (1,)
1-element BitArray{1}:
```

It returns `false`

while the following returns true?

```
julia> [(1,)][1] == (1,)
```

returns `true`

The same is also the case when I use the `egal` operator `(=== and .===)`.

I see this on Julia 0.6.1 and Julia 0.6.2 (juliabox); both on Linux 64-bit.
What am I missing ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `.==` iterates over a vector on the right side and over a tuple on the left size so essentially it is equivalent to wrapping the test

```
julia> (1,) == 1
false
```

in a one element `BitArray`.

To understand this consider the following examples of code:

```
julia> [(1,2),] .== (1,2)
2-element BitArray{1}:
 false
 false

julia> [(1,2),(1,2),(1,2)] .== (1,2)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")
Stacktrace:
 [1] _bcs1(::Base.OneTo{Int64}, ::Base.OneTo{Int64}) at .\broadcast.jl:70
 [2] _bcs at .\broadcast.jl:63 [inlined]
 [3] broadcast_shape at .\broadcast.jl:57 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [4] broadcast_indices at .\broadcast.jl:53 [inlined]
 [5] broadcast_c at .\broadcast.jl:313 [inlined]
 [6] broadcast(::Function, ::Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64}) at .\broadcast.jl:455

julia> [(1,)] .== ((1,),)
1-element BitArray{1}:
 true
```

In the first case `(1,2)` is compared to `1` and `2`. In the second one container dimensions do not match (2 over 3). In the third one everything matches.